# What do the characters I've found on this old gun mean?

Tags: translation, hanja, character-meanings

On an antique shotgun I was told had Korean origin I found the following (what I presume are Hanja?) characters. Four out of five I believe I have correctly identified. One character I could not find in the dictionary.

However, my only resources are Chinese and I know almost nothing about Chinese characters' usage in Korea<sup>†</sup>.

Side A:

```
[UNKNOWN CHARACTER] 製 特
```

Side B:

```
絞 筒
```

The unknown character is three stacked components in this basic form

```
-------
   人  
-------
     
-------
   巾  
-------
```

Though, the bottom component might well be `中`, there is quite a bit of tarnish obscuring it.

On Side A, the two characters that follow the unknown one seem to indicate "special manufacture".

One Side B, I get the translation "hang" or "twist" for character one, and "tube" for character two. To me, this might indicate the process of [rifling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rifling), but I could not find any use of these characters on the [Chinese character entry for rifling](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%86%9B%E7%B7%9A), and the barrel is old and I couldn't tell conclusively if it'd ever undergone that process.

#### Can someone help me translate these characters?<sup>*</sup>

<sup>† I'm also not certain the Korean origin of this piece, but that is what I was told.</sup>

<sup>* Please let me know if this might be a better fit for the Chinese language stack. I ask here with the idea that Korean usage of these characters might be idiomatic and more suitable for this sub. Thanks.</sup>

## Edit

I was able to take some acceptable close up imagery:

[image: Side A]

[image: Side B]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Questions about Hanja seem to be fine on Chinese.SE - relevant meta advice is on https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/what-questions-should-be-asked-on-chinese-se-instead-of-here and https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/what-should-korean-se-guidelines-consider-when-advising-on-posting-questions-her/ - unfortunately as this is a Beta site, we can't migrate questions, so you would have to cross-post to Chinese.SE yourself if you want to.  Of course as you say, there may be a uniquely Korean angle - a photo of the characters might be good!

Comment: @topomorto Updated.

Comment: at least for the very first character the bottom component indeed does look like 中

Comment: The construction looks like ⿱人布.

Comment: Well, the existence of Arabic numerals would put this in a modern period (probably early 20th century, or late 19th at the latest). Considering the state of Korea during this era (in short: not good), I think it's pretty unlikely to be of Korean origin.

Answer (score 4):

In the second photo,「絞筒」refers to the barrel of the gun.

In the first photo, the unknown character looks like「⿱人布」. I suggest that this is a slightly altered way of writing 「⿱布」, since the shape「人」is sometimes altered to「」at the top of characters:

> [image]

At least in Chinese records, this is a variant of either「布」or「希」.

> [image]
>
> ---
>
> [image]

1. If it's「布」, it would be a phonetic transcription character「포」, and is a proper noun marking the person, organisation, or location which manufactured (製) the gun.
2. If it's「希」, it may also be a proper noun, but alternatively you may choose to interpret this as「드물다・稀」(*rare, scarce*).「希特製」means something like *rare and uniquely made* or *special edition*; its semantic connection to *antique* would be obvious in this case.

---

Just from the photos, there's nothing unique that suggests that this is Korean; as an antique, it could be Chinese, Japanese, Korean, or Vietnamese.

---

**References:**

- [教育部異體字典](http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/home.do)

Comment: Thanks! This sounds plausible. Have you got any ideas on the “Side B” writing?

Comment: @1252748 updated answer.

Comment: Right, yeah I was pretty sure it refers to the barrel, but wondered what specifically it signifies.

Comment: @1252748 絞筒20...maybe the measurements of the gun barrel?

Comment: I’ve confirmed that 20 does refer to the barrel’s measurement, but the first character, do you agree, is “hang” or “twist”? How do you think that could relate?

Comment: @1252748 ah, I see where you're coming from.「絞筒」just refers to the barrel of the gun, and in this context「絞」may be referring to the [choke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(firearms)) ([Japanese Reference](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%B5%9E%E7%AD%92)). In general, [Chinese-derived words are two syllables](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/3820/reasons-for-chinese-changing-from-monosyllabic-to-disyllabic?noredirect=1&lq=1).